# Find it ${\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{n}}.$ , ${x_{n}=\frac{(n-1)c}{1+(n-1)c}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{1+(n-1)c} x_{n-2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

## QUESTION

The $x_{n}$ is defined recursively for some $x_{0}$ ,$x_{1}$ of the type$$\displaystyle{x_{n}=\frac{(n-1)c}{1+(n-1)c}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{1+(n-1)c} x_{n-2}}$$, where $c>0$. Find it $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{n}}.$

## I MADE SOME USEFUL PROCESS

We have
\begin{equation}
{x_n} = \frac{(n-1)c}{1+(n-1)c} {x_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{1+(n-1)c} {x_{n-2}} \Leftrightarrow {x_n} - {x_{n-2}} = (n-1)c \left( {x_{n-1}} - {x_n} \right)
\end{equation}

Let ${x_n} - {x_{n-1}} = {a_n}$. This results in ${a_n} - {a_{n-1}} + (n-1)c{a_n} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{{a_k}}{{a_{k-1}}} = \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)} \prod_{k=2}^{n} \Rightarrow {a_n} = {a_1} \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)}$.

Hence, ${x_m} - {x_{m-1}} = ({x_1} - {x_0}) \prod_{k=2}^{m} \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)} \bigg/ \sum_{m=1}^{n} \Rightarrow {x_n} = {x_0} + \sum_{m=1}^{n} \prod_{k=2}^{m} \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)}$.

Comment: A minor correction, I think it should be $x_n = x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)\sum_{m=1}^{n} \prod_{k=2}^{m} \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your results and taking into account @MartinR's comment
$${a_n} = {a_1} \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{\left( 1+(k-1)c \right)}=a_1\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{c^n\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{c}\right)}$$ and
$$x_n=x_0+(x_1-x_0)\,\,c^{\frac{1}{c}-1} \,e^{\frac{1}{c}}\, \color{blue}{\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{c}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{c}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{c}\right)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{c}\right)}}$$ and hoping that I am not mistaken, the asymptotics of the blue part should be
$$\left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{c}} e^{n-\frac{1}{c}}
   n^{-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{c}\right)} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)$$ and then the limit
$$x_n=x_0+(x_1-x_0)\,\,\color{blue}{c^{\frac{1}{c}-1} \,e^{\frac{1}{c}}\, \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? If I understand it correctly one needs $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{c^k\,\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{c}\right)}$$ but how did you compute that sum?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici the answer is $\displaystyle{\boxed{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n} = {x_1} \cdot \left( {1 + S} \right) - {x_0}S}}$